# relativelayout doesnnt fill the scrollbar height

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-relativelayout

I have RelativeLayout inside a scrolbar,as you see the height of relative layout doesn't fill the scrollbar height
how can I solve it?
I have another question, when I focus in an edittext the whole layut (parent layouyt) push up,I want just my layout put inside the scroll bar pushes up

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_Dead_Load"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/data_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_Dead_Load"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/material_info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_border">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wall_material"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/material_thickness"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="91dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:text="جنس مصالح"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/material_thickness"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:text="ضخامت mm"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/brick_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/material_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_wall_width"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/brick_material"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_wall_width"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/brick_material"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/brick_material"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/wall_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="نوع آجر"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_heavy"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/plastering_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/brick_layout"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_plastering_material"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/plastering_material"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_plastering_material"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/plastering_material"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plastering_material"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/plastering_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="نوع اندود"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_heavy"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/esther_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/plastering_layout"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/esther_material"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/esther_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="نوع آستر"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_heavy"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/esther_material_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/esther_material"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_esther_material"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/esther_material"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_esther_material"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/esther_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/esther_material_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/exterior_mortar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/esther_layout"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exterior_mortar_material"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/exterior_mortar_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="ملات بیرونی"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_heavy"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/exterior_mortar_material_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText_exterior_mortar_material"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/exterior_mortar_material"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_exterior_mortar_material"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_exterior_mortar_material"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/exterior_mortar_material_spinner"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/exterior_mortar_material_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/facing_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/exterior_mortar_layout"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facing_material"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/facing_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="نوع نما"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_heavy"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/facing_material_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText_facing_material"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facing_material"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_facing_material"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_facing_material"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/facing_material_spinner"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/facing_material_spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wall_loading_btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="wallLoading"
        android:text="محاسبه"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading_conclusion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wall_loading_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wall_loading_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/wall_loading_btn"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="جنس مصالح"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: change Layout's `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: solved...thanks
do you know how can i child layout push up when the softkey appears?